# C# DateTime Default Value Issue 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I am having trouble inserting a DateTime into a database with the following error:

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

I am aware that the SQL date must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999, however my date seems to remain at the  01/01/0001 00:00:00.

I have the following date defined in a web service method:

```
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime RecordTimeStamp { get; set; }
```

This is used in the following code to add into database

```
  sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@RecordTimeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = pCustomer.RecordTimeStamp;
```

This code takes its value from an aspx page with code

```
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  pCustomer.RecordTimeStamp = now;
```

I am trying to get this to insert the current date into the database, but it doesn't seem to change from the default.

Comment: FWIW, the value you are getting is the one of [`DateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) field... and is used for unassigned `DateTime` variables.

Comment: Which is what you get from DateTime dt = new DateTime()

Comment: What's the relationship between the web page and the web service? Do you submit the object to the web service? Your error suggests the value is getting lost at some point, so the field is using it's default value... OR the stored procedure isn't actually using the parameter.

Comment: is this ms sql 2008 or later? if ms sql 2005, its only accept `date` format only

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint where you're adding the parameter and examine the pCustomer.RecordTimeSamp?  Does it have the value you expect?  Are there any other Date fields in the table you're inserting into that aren't getting assigned a value?

Comment: Its sql 2008 & the stored procedure does use the parameter. I am trying to locate where it gets lost.

Comment: Using break points shows pCustomer.RecordTimeStamp to show the MinValue date.

Comment: the error is not successfully set the date of `pCustomer.RecordTimeStamp`

Answer (score 6):

Try to change the property

from:

> ```
> [DataMember]
> public DateTime RecordTimeStamp { get; set; }
> ```

to:

> ```
> [DataMember]
> public DateTime? RecordTimeStamp { get; set; }
> ```

Hopefully this will fix the issue. What happens is DateTime is NOT NULL data type and it enforces to put a default value there (01/01/0001) to make sure that non-null date will be submitted. I don't know why it does not accept altered value and throws out an "out of range" exception. That is something you might want to investigate further.